# is Count going to work here for orderno?

Tags: sql

I am getting a very high count, does this look correct? I want to know
how many order numbers we have in this time frame and according to order types.

```
                  SELECT                                                     
                            count(*)  IHORNO                                         
                            FROM      A1665AFCV.ROISH T01 LEFT OUTER JOIN          
                                      A1665AFCV.ROORSHE T02                        
                      ON        T01.IHORNO = T02.OHORNO                        
                      WHERE     IHIDAT >= 20151229                             
                       AND     OHORDT IN ('SO', 'MO', 'FB', 'WH')
```

Comment: Likely not.  Assuming cardinality between T01 and T02 is a 1-to-M as the left join will repeat records in T01. Most likely you would need to change count(*) to `count(distinct IHORNO)`  However if the cardinality is 1-1 then this should be fine.  To know for certain search fro a particular IHORNO  if you get a count > 1 then you know it's not working.

Comment: `IHIDAT` and `OHORDT` are columns of which table

Comment: ihidat is from roish; ohordt is from roorshe

Comment: Probably not? It's hard to tell without table structures or sample data. You should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You asked, "I am getting a very high count, does this look correct?"**

Likely not.  The left join will cause records in T01 to demoralize to repeating occurrences for each record in T02 assuming a 1-M relationship (t01 to t02).  If assumed cardinality (relationship) between tables is true then:

1. count(*) will inflate the count of orders due to the join
2. count(distinct T01.IHORNO) however will count unique IHORNO values which I believe is what you're after.  (unique orders count with other limiting critiera)

.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT T01.IHORNO) IHORNO
FROM A1665AFCV.ROISH T01
LEFT OUTER JOIN A1665AFCV.ROORSHE T02
  ON T01.IHORNO = T02.OHORNO
WHERE IHIDAT >= 20151229
  AND OHORDT IN ('SO', 'MO', 'FB', 'WH')
```